# calculates the difference between the total in php

Tags: php

I want to seek a reduction in the amount of 2 days. 
that is today reduced to the date of before today.

for example :

```
$dateNow = date('Y-m-d');
$getDate = "2014-07-30";
$return = 25;
```

please, give me solution.
thanks...

Comment: [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php?rq=1)

Comment: of these examples the result of 2 years, 3 months, 2 days. 
if i just want to get total days from 2 years, 3 months, 2 days? thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
$dateNow = new DateTime(date('Y-m-d'));
$getDate = new DateTime("2014-07-30");
$interval = $getDate->diff($dateNow);
$return = $interval->days;
echo "Difference  ".$return." Days";
```